# How to prevent a bootstrap navbar from collapsing when window resizing

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want my navbar to collapse on all pages except one where I want it to stay expanded at 1140px wide. How would I do this? here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/82scyezw/)

Here is my navbar

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      
      <div class="navbar-inline">
        <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="/Home">
          <img alt="Brand" src="~/Images/brandImagenew.png">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
      </ul>
      @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "stay expanded at 1140px". Your navbar doesn't collapse into mobile view until 768px unless you're referring to something else or you mean you want it mobile until 1140px? Also, is the Search Bar meant to be inline with the links or pushing them down like in your jsfiddle?

Comment: when the navbar shrinks to ~768 the 'about', 'contact' and login labels from ('_loginPartial') get collapsed. I want to stop that from happening.

Answer (score 1):

The added CSS resets the navbar so it won't respond, you probably don't need all of that CSS but you can check the link below for more info.

Here's a link to the Bootstrap Docs for [Non-Responsive CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/non-responsive.css) where you can pull out specifically what you may need.

Also, there seems to be a closing div tag missing from your `navbar-header` class in your jsfiddle.

```css
/**FOR DEMO ONLY**/

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default #search-group {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
}
/** THE ABOVE FOR DEMO ONLY**/

.navbar-default .container .navbar-header,
.navbar-default .container .navbar-collapse {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
/* Always float the navbar header */

.navbar-default .navbar-header {
  float: left;
}
/* Undo the collapsing navbar */

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  display: block !important;
  height: auto !important;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  overflow: visible !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  display: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  border-top: 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  margin-left: -15px;
}
/* Always apply the floated nav */

.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
  float: left;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding: 15px;
}
/* Redeclare since we override the float above */

.navbar-default .navbar-nav.navbar-right {
  float: right;
}
/* Undo custom dropdowns */

.navbar-default .navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-width: 0 1px 1px;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #333;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus,
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #428bca !important;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #999 !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
/* Undo form expansion */

.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
/* Copy-pasted from forms.less since we mixin the .form-inline styles. */

.navbar-default .navbar-form .form-group {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-form .form-control {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-form .form-control-static {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-form .input-group {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-form .input-group .input-group-addon,
.navbar-default .navbar-form .input-group .input-group-btn,
.navbar-default .navbar-form .input-group .form-control {
  width: auto;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-form .input-group > .form-control {
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-form .control-label {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-form .radio,
.navbar-default .navbar-form .checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-form .radio label,
.navbar-default .navbar-form .checkbox label {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-form .radio input[type="radio"],
.navbar-default .navbar-form .checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.navbar-form .has-feedback .form-control-feedback {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <div class="navbar-inline">
        <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="/Home">
          <img alt="Brand" src="http://placehold.it/100x25/ff0/ff0">
        </a>

        <div class="form-group" id="search-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="searchQuery" name="searchQuery">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```