# How to prevent bootstrap navbar buttons from stacking

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to design a responsive page.

This is how it looks like in a wide browser.
[image]

It changes to the ff. when I make it narrow:
[image]

What I want to happen is this:
[image]

This is my code for it:

```css
/**For Eample Only So the Icons are Visible*/

.navbar-ct-blue {
  background: #1B96BF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/pixeden-stroke-7-icon/1.2.3/dist/pe-icon-7-stroke.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-ct-blue navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-justified">
      <li class="navbar-nav">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="pe-7s-piggy" style="color: white;"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-nav">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="pe-7s-cash" style="color: white;"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-nav">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="pe-7s-wallet" style="color: white;"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I have looked at these links, but I couldn't find the answer. Please help.

[How to prevent Bootstrap navbar from displaying in multiple lines without collapsing them into an icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405170/how-to-prevent-bootstrap-navbar-from-displaying-in-multiple-lines-without-collap)

[How to prevent a bootstrap navbar from collapsing when window resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642906/how-to-prevent-a-bootstrap-navbar-from-collapsing-when-window-resizing)

[Centering navbar buttons in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663874/centering-navbar-buttons-in-bootstrap)

Comment: are you sure that this your code for the navbar?

Comment: does that happen in all browsers?? also have you tried inspecting the css for the nav bar. It looks like its not set to inline-block when its at a certain width. i assume there is media query in the css. You can check this when you inspect the page

Comment: can you provide a link for the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing this happen since the `nav-justified` class only uses `display:table-cell` above 768px:

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
 .nav-justified > li {
   display: table-cell;
   width: 1%
}
```

Here are two examples that solve this:

Using `nav-justified`:

```css
.navbar.navbar-ct-blue {
  background: #1B96BF;
  border: 1px solid #1B96BF;
  max-height: 50px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar.navbar-ct-blue .nav-justified > li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%
}
.navbar.navbar-ct-blue .nav-justified > li > a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.navbar.navbar-ct-blue .nav-justified > li > a:hover {
  color: #00F2FF;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/pixeden-stroke-7-icon/1.2.3/dist/pe-icon-7-stroke.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-ct-blue navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">

  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-justified">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="pe-7s-piggy"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="pe-7s-cash"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="pe-7s-wallet"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Using the Grid:

```css
.navbar.navbar-ct-blue {
  background: #1B96BF;
  border: 1px solid #1B96BF;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar.navbar-ct-blue .nav-row span {
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.navbar.navbar-ct-blue .nav-row span:hover {
  color: #00F2FF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/pixeden-stroke-7-icon/1.2.3/dist/pe-icon-7-stroke.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-ct-blue" role="navigation">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row nav-row text-center">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <a href="#"><span class="pe-7s-piggy"></span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <a href="#"><span class="pe-7s-cash"></span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <a href="#"><span class="pe-7s-wallet"></span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

To give the `<li class="navbar-nav">` is obviously wrong. Removing that could fix it. Additionally, as Tasos said `inline-block` for the list item should do it. Sure, look in the corresponding media query.